# filter mysql output to only print what you need

Tags: mysql

if i want to print the columns for a specific table i type `desc table_name` or `show columns from table_name` but the output of these commands is too long, and all the time does not fit my screen width, so i append `\G` to print the result by line, but still not what i need.

how can i only print the field name, from something that look

```
*************************** 6. row ***************************
  Field: email
   Type: varchar(255)
   Null: NO
    Key: 
Default: NULL
  Extra: 
*************************** 7. row ***************************
```

for example a command like `desc table_name\G grep Field cut -d' ' -f1`
is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='table_name';
```